# Debug Javascript in VS 2017 without [dynamic] window

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I recently lost the ability to step through Javascript code without having a separate [dynamic] window containing the same file pop up while debugging. This is extremely annoying for several reasons, of which the primary three are:

1. I frequently make edits to the [dynamic] window by accident, where they are ignored.
2. Debugging tooltips do not work in the [dynamic] window.
3. Pressing F12 to jump to a variable/function definition does not
   work.

I came across an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726430/get-rid-of-dynamic-javascript-views-in-visual-studio) addressing this issue but none of the proposed solutions helped. I know what I want is possible because only a month ago my Visual Studio did not behave like this.

I am using VS 2017.

Comment: THIS!  TOTALLY THIS!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

And then debug your app with breakpoint in your JavaScript, view the result in your side.

[image]

Comment: @Serene Taleb-Agha, What about this issue? Is it helpful for you? Please feel free to share us the latest information about this issue, I will follow up it in time:)

Comment: It IS enabled, and I still get thrown into the dynamic window for debugging.  This solution worked in VS 2019, but I just upgraded to VS 2022, and now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if not then enable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging in VS 2017

Then debug with Chrome browser ( or IE) like :

[image]

Now if you add break point in your .js file it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Uncheck a Checkbox From List**

Options > Debugging > Bring Visual Studio to the foreground when breaking in the debugger