# JavaScript file running as Dynamic in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.
Some times when i update JavaScript file and debug the solution in my local machine, after opening the page in Browser, my JavaScript file showing as [Dynamic] mode, it is not taking my latest script code.

This issue i am getting not always, but some times. For what reason this issue would be happening, lack of any my user credentials?

How to get rid of this issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Which VS version did you use? In VS2017, please disable/enable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging, debug it again. If you use old VS version, maybe you could refer to this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726430/get-rid-of-dynamic-javascript-views-in-visual-studio

Comment: i am using VS 2015. my issue got fixed. there is a option in IE that General -- > Settings --> "Every time I visit the webpage" under Version Stored pages. Thank You.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could post it as the answer, and mark it. So we could close this case. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could resolve this in IE as

1. Go to Settings - Internet Options
2. With "General" tab selected and under "Browsing history" click "Settings"
3. With "Temporary Internet Files" tab selected click on "Every time I visit the
   webpage" under "Check for newer versions of stored pages"
4. Hit 'OK"
5. Hit "Apply" and "OK"