# TypeScript files are loaded in [dynamic] tabs instead of focusing the active source tab

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

In this scenario I have a .Net Core 2 web project, and working on one TypeScript file.  It used to be (if I recall correctly) that errors should break on the opened source tab.  Instead now I'm seeing Visual Studio (2017) break on a NEW tab with the `[dynamic]` tag next to the tab name; however, the path of this file (when viewing properties) is a file path to the SAME source file I have open! :(  It looks like this (lines are tabs):

`| File.ts | Files.ts [dynamic] # |`
*(#: the second tab is also locked)*

It's been awhile now and I can't recall if this is normal, or if I'm missing something?

TS file structure:

```
Project/
       wwwroot/js/ (.js and .js.map files, where 'outDir' points in tsconfig)
       Scripts/ (.ts files, and where 'rootDir' points in tsconfig)
```

Things I already tried and other info:

1. Made sure all `.ts` file actions are "TypeScriptCompile".
2. Verified that the `.map` files correctly point to the source.
3. The `.js` and `.js.map` files are stored together in the `wwwroot\js` folder.
4. The `.ts` files exist in a `Scripts` folder in the project root.
5. Right-clicking on the `.ts` file in question under the `Script Documents` node during a debug session shows that the `URL` reference `file//C:///...pathtofile...`, which is correct (obviously! or it wouldn't be found in the first place)
6. Made sure script debugging is enabled in IE (not sure that matters for VS, since I think it still works regardless).
7. Breakpoints, including the `debugger;` keyword, always break in the dynamic tab and never my opened source tab.

Is this normal behaviour? Thanks.

*Specs: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, and debugging with IE11.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854370/1236397

For some reason my files (coming in and out of Git source control) ended up invalid. They ARE text files, but ASCII text files. I converted one file to UTF8 as a test and now the `.ts` file in my working tab gets focused instead of a dynamic tab! I think this should be a bug really, not sure.  I don't understand why I can edit text `.ts` files easily in Visual Studio and have it get confused and load it dynamically.

To convert files in Visual Studio there are two options:

1. `Save As ...`, then click the arrow next to `Save` and select `Save with Encoding...`.
2. Change using `File->Advanced Save Options...`.  If you don't have that, then go to `Tools->Customize...->Commands`, select `File` in the dropdown next to `Menu bar:`, then click `Add Command...`, and you'll see it under the `Files` category.

You can also use Notepad++, under the `Encoding` menu.