# Get rid of [dynamic] JavaScript views debugged automatically in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

It started some time ago, since that day when I click *'Start Debugging'* button in Visual Studio, project opens only after hitting 2 breakpoints in dynamically generated Javascript files. Everytime I need to click 'Continue'(F5) button.

I didn't install any third party extension. It happens only with **Chrome** browser. If I start using **IE** browser then project starts without hitting any breakpoint.

Googled but couldn't find any useful solution.

I have already tried asnwers in this post: [Get rid of [dynamic] JavaScript views in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726430/get-rid-of-dynamic-javascript-views-in-visual-studio)

I want to get rid off this uncomfortable behaviour. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you still want to debug JavaScript but the [dynamic] nodes are problematic. Or do you not want to debug JS at all? (Script debugging is disabled by default in VS2019 now, but can be enabled.)

Comment: Yes, I want to debug Javascript but the [dynamic] nodes are problematic. Temporarily I am using Visual Studio with 'Script Debugging(Disabled)' option.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  This just started happening to me (VS 2019 Enterprise, Edge 103.0.1264.49)

Comment: No, unfortunately